# Use amsul pickdate in my ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker, morris.js

I'm trying to use amsul datepicker (called pickdate) to pass dates to my ajax call...

I have two input fields, (from and to):

```
<input id="from"> <input id="to">
```

My Js code:

```
var $input = $('#from').pickadate({
    formatSubmit : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    format : 'fro!m: dd-mm-yyyy',
    hiddenName : true
});
 var $input = $('#to').pickadate({
    formatSubmit : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    format : 'fro!m: dd-mm-yyyy',
    hiddenName : true
});
```

Firs, I don't know how to take the values from pickadte, and pass them into show_ersults function below...

And my ajax call to morris chart:

```
function show_result(){ 
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {get_values: true},
    success: function(response) {
        Morris.Line({
            element: 'morris-line-chart',
            data: response,
            xkey: 'Timestamp',
            ykeys: ['Value'],
            labels: ['Income Today'],
            barColors: ['#2F2FFF'],
            smooth: false,
            resize: true
        });
    }
});}
```

(my url show be like url: `'ajax.php?from='+ from...`)

My question is, How can I pass the dates of datepicker to my ajax call..

My php (I've it prepared, i guess) looks like this :

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/database/db_connect.php";
include_once($path);

if (isset($_POST['from']) AND isset($_POST['to'])) {

    $from = $_POST['from']; 
    $from = $_POST['to'];
    $var = array();

    $query = "SELECT Date as Timestamp, ROUND(Value,0) as Value 
    FROM KPI WHERE idName=6 AND Date >= '$from' AND Date <= '$to'" 
    or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); 

    $result = $link->query($query); 
    while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $var[] = $obj;
    }
    echo json_encode($var);
}
```

Your help will be apreciated.
Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

To send the data modifies ajax call in data param:

```
function show_result(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'from': $('#from').val(), 'to': $('#to').val()},
        success: function(response) {
             Morris.Line({
                 element: 'morris-line-chart',
                 data: response,
                 xkey: 'Timestamp',
                 ykeys: ['Value'],
                 labels: ['Income Today'],
                 barColors: ['#2F2FFF'],
                 smooth: false,
                 resize: true
         });
    }
});}
```

And change this in the server:

```
 $from = $_POST['from']; 
 $to   = $_POST['to'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as you are requesting, but I used Bootstrap datepicker instead. And I did not use PHP.
First of all you need to look for the event when you select a day in Amsul datepicker and then pass that to ajax call. I'll show you a little example using morris and bootstrap datepicker. This works perfectly for me.

HTML

```
<div class="ibox-content">
     <div class="inner toast-bottom-full-width">
           <label>Select a day</label>
           <label for="fromdate" class='field prepend-icon'>
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                <input type='text' id='fromdate' name="datepicker-from" style="width:90%" class="gui-input" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" placeholder="" />
           </label>
      </div>

        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
        <div id="morris-bar-chart"></div></div>
```

JavaScript

```
   function hourString(hour) {
     if (hour === 0) {
         return "12:00 am";
     }
     if (hour < 12) {
         return hour + ":00 am";
     }
     if (hour === 12) {
         return "12:00 pm";
     }
     return (hour - 12) + ":00 pm";
 }

  var ordersPackChart =
     Morris.Bar({
         element: 'morris-bar-chart',
         data: [],
         xkey: 'y',
         ykeys: ['a'],
         ymax: 1000,
         labels: ['Pack per hour'],
         hideHover: true,
         resize: true,
         barColors: ['#ed5565'],
         parseTime: false
     });

 function packResult(historydate, result) {
     result = JSON.parse(result);

     var data = [];
     for (var hour = 6; hour < 24; hour++) {

         var numberPack = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i < result.Result.length; i++) {
             if (result.Result[i].PACK_HOUR == hour) {
                 numberPack = result.Result[i].NUM_ORDER_PACK;
                 break;
             }
         }

         data.push({ y: hourString(hour), a: numberPack });
     }

     ordersPackChart.setData(data);
 }


 $(document).ready(function () {        
     $("#fromdate").datepicker({
         autoclose: true
     }).change(dateChanged)
       .on('changeDate', dateChanged);
      });

 function dateChanged(ev) {
     $(this).datepicker('hide');

     var day = $('#fromdate').val();

     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: '@Url.Action("GetQueryResult")',
         context: document.body,
         data: {
             querySetName: 'dashboard-packorder-statistics',
             queryName: 'OrderPack',
             historydate: day
         },
         success: function (result) {
             packResult(ordersPackChart.HISTORY_DATE, result);
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
             var message = "ErrorStatus: " + xhr.status + "  ReadyState: " + xhr.readyState;
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: And also when is a range picker I'd like to use HighCharts. They work really well for those range selectors